# Create a Data Extension report with Data View and Journey information

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, journeybuilder, dataextensions, data-views

My goal is to create a Data Extension (DE_Journeys_Report) that will contain a report of different Journeys, extracted from different Data Extensions.
I need the following fields from the **Sent Data View**:

- JobID
- ListID
- BatchID
- SubscriberID
- TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID
- SubscriberKey
- EventDate

I also need the Journey Name from the **Journey Data View**, and finally, I need to get some other fields from the entry Data Extensions of different Journeys:

- Canal
- Email
- Phone
- Contract
- Version

I think I have the first part of my Query, which is very simple and it just extracts all the fields I need from my two Data Views (Sent and Journey) and it saves them into a new Data Extension (DE_Journeys_Report) that for the moment does not have any Primary Key (maybe this is an error, but this is why I'm here seeking for guidance):

```
SELECT A.JobID, A.ListID, A.BatchID, A.SubscriberID, A.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID,
    A.Subscriberkey, A.EventDate, C.JourneyName
FROM _Sent A
INNER JOIN _JourneyActivity B
    ON A.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID = B.JourneyActivityObjectID
INNER JOIN _Journey C
    ON B.VersionID = C.VersionID
WHERE A.EventDate >= convert(date, getDate())
AND A.EventDate < convert(date, dateadd(day,1,getDate()))
AND (C.JourneyName = 'JourneyName1' OR
    C.JourneyName = 'JourneyName2'
)
```

Getting the rest of the fields from the Data Extension of one of the Journeys should be quite easy too, but I can't figure out how am I supposed to connect the results of the second query, with the results of the first one, already saved on my target Data Extension.
I tried to connect the two results with SubscriberKey and JourneyName, but this doesn't work correctly as in one Journey the same Subscriber can enter many times.
Can you please give me some suggestions/ideas/advice?
Do I need a Primary Key on my target Data Extension to be able to link the two queries correctly?
If yes, which one should it be my PrimaryKey or PrimaryKeys?

Any help will be highly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not much use in retrospect, but you could use Send Logging to capture the values Canal, Email, Phone etc. SendLogs contain JobID, ListID, BatchID, SubscriberID and you can add these other fields you need from the entry data just by adding corresponding fields in your send log table. It'd then be easy to incorporate these fields into the query you have. The PK on your table should be on JobID, ListID, BatchID, SubscriberID.

Comment: Thank you @Macca, yes I'm finally using the SendLog DE to get all the results I need and then I will do a query on this DE to my new one. If you make your comment an answer, I can mark it as correct. Cheers!